# From argv to execvp

Tags: c, pointers, posix

So I have a problem I haven't been able to solve.
I'm writing a C program that executes some OS functions via pipes. The execution is done with execvp(const char *file, char *const argv[]);.

In my main function I would like to take the whole line passed to the program (argv) except for the first char-array and pass it to grep. Everything works at the moment, but I keep getting the warning:

```
warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
const char* grep = argv;
                   ^
```

My code looks like following. In the clause `if(1 < argc)` i want to be able to send the `argv` with the first post modified to `newPipeline` on the same format as printenv, sort and less.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv, char **envp){

    const char* printenv[] = {"printenv", NULL, NULL};
    const char* sort[] = {"sort", NULL, NULL};
    const char* less[] = {"less", NULL, NULL};
    if(1<argc){
        argv[0] = "grep";
        const char* grep = argv; 
        const char* const* commands[] = {printenv, sort, grep, less, NULL};
        newPipeline((char* const**)commands, 0, STDIN_FILENO);
    }
    //FROM HERE ON IT WORKS
    else{
        const char* const* commands[] = {printenv, sort, less, NULL};
        newPipeline((char* const**)commands, 0, STDIN_FILENO);
    }
    if(signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN) == SIG_ERR){
        perror("A problem with the children");
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

I know that the pointer types are wrong. Should I build up a completely new array for `grep` or should I, as I am trying to do now, cast pointers into the right kind of pointers. If the later, which pointers would that be?

Comment: You should copy your array(argv) in another one to work with

Comment: `argv` is not `const`. You are free to modify it as you wish (and so will `grep`), so make a copy every time you pass it on.

Comment: you want to join the elements of argv into a single string separated by a space, right? that's what you're missing in that case

Comment: @someguy. Nope. Just pass the vector along as-is.

Comment: @Mad Physicist: doesn't make sense then. `grep` is a string, not an array strings.

Comment: @someguy. I was referring to `grep` the program. That is what OP was going to open a pipe to.

Comment: @Mad Physicist: nvm i didn't look at the manual for `execvp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your grep variable needs to be a pointer to an array of strings or an array of strings (not simply a string).

Something like:

```
argv[0] = "grep";
const char** grep = (const char**)argv; //make grep point to the modified char** argv;
```

should do it, or construct a new array:

```
const char* grep[argc+1]; 
grep[0] = "grep";
grep[argc]=NULL;
for(int i=1; i<argc; i++){
  grep[i] = argv[i];
}
```

BTW, I believe you only need one `NULL` at the end of each string array.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies here

```
const char* grep = argv;
```

C does not provide internal type casting for const types. And if your motive is to copy the array of `argv` into `grep`, it's wrong, use `strcpy` or any such function to make a clone of that array.